# How to return in case of ctr+c in getline?

Tags: c, signals, getline, sigint

I know how to ignore signals like `Ctrl+C` when getting inputs using 'getline', but I am facing difficulty to send a continue message to a while loop when ever the SIGINT signal is sent let me show you what I mean.

This is the effect I want to get. Like the once you get when you click `Ctrl+c` in a bash terminal.

[image]

When ever you send the SIGINT signal a newline is printed and the loop goes on. Here is the code I currently have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handlec(int sig)
{
    signal(sig, handlec);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char *cmd = NULL;
    size_t len;

    signal(SIGINT, handlec);

    while (1)
    {
        printf("insert ");
        getline(&cmd, &len, stdin);
    }
    return (1);
}
```

In this program when ever `ctr+c` is pressed the same `^C` message is printed and a new line is printed but the loop isn't auto continued until the user presses `<RETURN>`. How would you approach this problem? I tried to use goto loops, but there is no such thing as global labels so it was hard to direct the while loop in the main function from the other function. If it matters, I am using my own getline function so I can do any manipulation in there if that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom of reinstalling the signal handler in the signal handler suggests you're expecting a broken historical behavior where signal handlers are self-disarming and interrupting. This is still allowed by the standards but not the behavior on any modern system. You should forget the legacy `signal` function and use `sigaction`, which lets you control the behavior you want.

```
struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = handler, /* .sa_flags = 0 */ };
sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, 0);
```

The default flags (not including `SA_RESTART`) will give you the behavior you want (interrupting the `getline` and causing it to return with an `EINTR` error). You do not need to rearm the signal handler from itself. Also you can't use `printf` from there; you must use `write` or some other async-signal-safe function to produce output.